# Gradle sync failed.Basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: gradle, methods, compilation, synchronization

org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compile() for arguments [me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.